# Replicating a scrolling & fading out text

Tags: java, text

I'm pretty new to Java and decided to work on making a simple 2D game (based off a tutorial) and would like to add a roughly similar effect to the text below. It doesn't have to be identical, but it would be nice to have it similar using the scrolling or the ability that if multiple points were gotten at once it wouldn't overlap.

My class that's dealing with generating obstacles and doing scores: http://pastebin.com/KGWivKFr

(The counter currently works fine it's only the code for the +10 to disappear that I'm struggling with - GIFs below + in first post to help illustrate - couldn't post more than 2 links as my first post).

[What I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDlrz.gif)

Comment: 1. [A visual of a minimum of what I'd like to achieve, with the ability for the multiple '+10's to stack above and not conflict.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAGNn.gif)

2. [The text effect that would like to be replicated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t15O.gif)